# Import Network Profiles from windows into Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, password, windows-10, migration

I'm new here, just decided to switch to Ubuntu, but before I go into the installation, I want to make sure that I will be able to import Previously connected Network Profiles, I have already exported them on Windows, and they are kept in XML format.

Can I import those XML files into Ubuntu? If yes, how can I do so?

I'm currently using Windows 10, If you need anymore info, please leave a comment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just have a normal networking setup, setting it up fresh will be a piece of cake provided you know what your Wifi password is (if you're using wireless internet): you won't need the Windows XML's.  If you have a directly wired connection, it will probably auto-configure. ***Make sure you backup all data before installing Ubuntu.***

Comment: Yes , this is the problem ,  some of the networks -that I have previously connected to - don't provide the network info -like password you logged in -  in clear text , I tried to reach network password through  CMD or network settings , but failed , it tells me that password is absent or not shown .             I doubt I could get a password for those networks again ,  and that's why I 'm asking if there is a way to import XML .

and  thanks for reminding about the backup